# How to have 2 pagination on the same page

Tags: paginator, knppaginator

how to have 2 paginations on the same page and that the change of one does not impact the second?
I currently have 2 paginations on my page, and when I go to page 2 on the first, it puts me on page 2 also on the second, how can I prevent this? THANKS

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz37f.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miUbT.png)

i use symfony 6.3

i do nothing, because i don't know what i can do

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function getPaginationNotFinish()
{
    $request = $this->requestStack->getMainRequest();
    $page = $request->query->getInt('pages', 1);
    $limit = 1;
    $articleQuery = $this->getAllNotFinish();

    return $this->paginator->paginate($articleQuery, $page, $limit, ["pageParameterName"=>"pages"]);
}
```